# How to store multiple user responses in Ruby for a trip expense program

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a program that asks the user how many trips they have taken and prompts them a number of times depending on their answer. After that I want to ask the user for their trip locations and store their answers. How can I store the multiple answers for use later in the program?

Eventually I want to be able to also ask how much was spent on lodging, transit, etc... and store those answers as well.

This is what I have so far:

```
# asks the user how many trips they've taken and prompts them that number of times
puts "How many trips did you take?"
trip_count = gets.chomp.to_i

# prompts the user the trip locations and stores them in a hash
trip_count.times { |x| puts "Where did you go for trip ##{x+1}?" 
trip_location = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "How much did you spend on lodging?"
lodging_cost = gets.chomp.to_i}
```

Comment: without user's information, how could you know which answers belongs to who even you store the answers?

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby pattern to use here is `map`:

```
trips = trip_count.times.map do |i|
  puts "Where did you go for trip ##{x+1}?"

  trip_location = gets.chomp.to_i

  puts "How much did you spend on lodging?"
  lodging_cost = gets.chomp.to_i

  {
    location: trip_location,
    cost: lodging_cost
  }
end
```

Where that returns an array of Hash structures with keys indicating which values are which.

> Tip: Get in the habit of using `do ... end` instead of `{ ... }` for multi-line blocks of code. The `{ ... }` form works best for short, single-line cases.